# Incorrect redirect after enter incorrect password in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

On MVC, I added top the َ`Admincontroller` `[Authorize]` to check if it was not logged in redirect to the `loginpage`.
When you want to enter the `Adminpage`, it redirect to `Loginpage`.if you enter the correct information Send it to the admin page if you enter the wrong Then enter the correct password it redirect to `HomePage`
I do not know what the problem is

> Controller Login

```
       // GET: /Account/Login
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Login

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }

    //
```

> View Login

```
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
        {.....
```

> Web.Config

```
   <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login" timeout="2880"></forms>
</authentication>
```

> Admin Controller

```
       [Authorize]
    [AttributeRouting.Web.Mvc.GET("Admin")]
    public ActionResult Admin()
    {

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: We don't know what the problem is either. explain your problem clearly. i personally did not understand what you said.

Comment: When in login page enter username and password true for the first time redirect to admin page but if enter username password incorrect for the first time then enter corrrect redirect to homepage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't store the information on where the redirect should be.
Let me explain.

1. You browse to admin
2. You get redirected on the login page.
   *Now your `ReturnUrl` variable points to Admin controller.*
3. Authentication process

   - If the process fails. Your new `ReturnUrl` variable is set to null. That's why you get redirected on your Home Page.
   - If the process succeeds the `ReturnUrl` variable will not reset and you will get redirected to the Admin page.

---

The solution for this is to store with some other way your `ReturnUrl` variable or make sure it gets passed with the credentials.

One simple solution is to edit your `LoginController` and instead of this piece of code

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
   return View(model);
}
...
switch (result)
{
...
case SignInStatus.Failure:
   default:
   ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
   return View(model);
}
```

use this code:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
   ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
   return View(model);
}

...
switch (result)
{
...
   case SignInStatus.Failure:
   default:
   ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
   ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
   return View(model);
}
```

### EDIT: Updated Code

Updated switch statement too.

Comment: I did it but did not fix it When the wrong password arrives the returnurl does not change but I do not know why the incorrect redirects

Comment: Oh sorry didnt notice this earlier you must change this to the switch statement too. See my latest edit